# Adding tags to ng-tags-input with selenium

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, ng-tags-input

I'm trying to automate testing of a webpage where I added ng-tags-input. I'm having difficulties adding tags to ng-tags-input with the selenium webdriver. Selenium finds the element but the sendKeys() function does not add text to it.

Selenium Code (v. 2.49.0):

```
 driver.findElement(By.id("tags")).sendKeys("test, one, two, three");
```

HTML:

```
 <tags-input ng-model="tempTags" id="tags" ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }" on-tag-added="convertToTagString()" on-tag-removed="convertToTagString()"></tags-input>
```

Final HTML:

```
<tags-input ng-model="tempTags" id="tags" ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }" on-tag-added="convertToTagString()" on-tag-removed="convertToTagString()" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-valid-max-tags ng-valid-min-tags ng-valid-leftover-text ng-touched">
<div class="host" tabindex="-1" ng-click="eventHandlers.host.click()" ti-transclude-append="">
  <div class="tags" ng-class="{focused: hasFocus}">
     <ul class="tag-list">
        <!-- ngRepeat: tag in tagList.items track by track(tag) -->
     </ul>
     <input class="input ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" autocomplete="off" ng-model="newTag.text" ng-model-options="{getterSetter: true}" ng-keydown="eventHandlers.input.keydown($event)" ng-focus="eventHandlers.input.focus($event)" ng-blur="eventHandlers.input.blur($event)" ng-paste="eventHandlers.input.paste($event)" ng-trim="false" ng-class="{'invalid-tag': newTag.invalid}" ng-disabled="disabled" ti-bind-attrs="{type: options.type, placeholder: options.placeholder, tabindex: options.tabindex, spellcheck: options.spellcheck}" ti-autosize="" type="text" placeholder="Add a tag" spellcheck="true" style="width: 69px;"><span class="input" style="visibility: hidden; width: auto; white-space: pre; display: none;">Add a tag</span>
  </div>
</div>
</tags-input>
```

Comment: Have you tried sending to the `input` instead instead of the `tags-input`?

Comment: I thought I tried that but I did it again to confirm and it worked! Thank you  qqilihq.

Answer (score 1):

SendKeys() to the xpath of the **input**(not ng-tags-input) worked.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"tags\"]/div/div/input")).sendKeys("test, five");
```